# Why is this ajax post request executing a GET request with the data right before the post request is executed in Nodejs express?

Tags: ajax, node.js, post, express, get

I have an interesting problem here. Here is the form where I want to use ajax to execute a post request on to the server.

```
replyPrefix = "<div id='addCommentContainer'><form class='addCommentForm' name='addcomment' id='addCommentForm'>" +
            "<div class='input-group'>" +
                "<input class='form-control' class='commentContent' type='text' placeholder='Comment!' name='commentContent'>" +
                "<input class='form-control' class='commentParent' type='hidden' name='parent' value='";
replySuffix = "'>" +
                "<span class='input-group-btn'>" +
                    "<button class='btn btn-danger' type='submit' class='submitButton'>submit</button>" +
                "</span>" +
            "</div></form></div>";
```

(The value for the reply is inserted inbetween this form's prefix/suffix. Note that this form and code was executing post requests fine before I tried moving to ajax)

Here is the jquery where I execute the ajax post request

```
$('.addCommentForm').submit(function() {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/addcomment",
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log("success:");
                        //alert(data);
                    },
                    error: function(e) {
                        console.log("error:");
                    }
                });
            });
```

And here is the nodejs express code.

```
// handle add comment call
router.post('/addcomment', function(req, res) {

//var obj = {};
console.log('body: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
//res.send(req.body);

//return;

var db = req.db;
var collection = db.get('comments');

// grab parent id if available
var parent = req.body.parent;
var content = req.body.commentContent;

console.log("parent: " + parent);
console.log("content: " + content);

// if no parent available, add new bubble
if (!parent || parent == "") {
    console.log("Adding a bubble...");
    addBubble(db, collection, content);
}
// otherwise, add comment to tree
else {
    console.log("Adding a comment...");
    addComment(db, collection, content, parent);
}

// DEBUG
//console.log(parent);
//console.log(req.body.commentContent);

//res.redirect('/');
});
```

The post request via ajax is being executed properly, and the reply gets added to the database and everything, however the page is constantly being reloaded when the post request is executed because of this get request that gets sent right before it everytime the form is submitted.

```
body: {"commentContent":"asdf","parent":"55f778aab671e4b41d05c6a7"}
parent: 55f778aab671e4b41d05c6a7
content: asdf
Adding a comment...
GET /?commentContent=asdf&parent=55f778aab671e4b41d05c6a7 200 65.626 ms - 53620
POST /addcomment - - ms - -
```

(Above is the console output, the question I have is why this get request with the data I submitted is being executed? How do I prevent that from happening?)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are submitting the form and the ajax request. Try adding the following to prevent the default submit action (GET).

```
.submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //ajax code
}
```